# Concatentation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

Is there any way to concatenate two strings without using '+' operator or CONCATENATION function?

Comment: no others operator is available in sql server with these 2 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: any specific reason you are looking for other options? these two are the only option in sql server as far as I know. concat() function is better than + as it will handle the null value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stuff() function - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms188043(v=sql.110))

```
SELECT STUFF('One match', 5, 0, 'day ')
```

Comment: `STUFF()` is a function too.

Answer (score 2):

There are 7 ways to concatenate

1. `CONCAT()`
2. `CONCAT_WS()`
3. `CONVERT()`
4. `CAST()`
5. `TRY_CONVERT()`
6. `TRY_CAST()`
7. `STUFF()`

You can refer [this](https://www.certifiedhack.com/2019/03/7-ways-to-concatenate-string-and-number.html) article